# Making a Server Directory Accessible via LAN but not Externally

Tags: mamp

I have installed MAMP on our server to allow all web developers to code from the same area.

It's currently accessible via our 192.x.x.x IP address (i.e. internally).

However, it's also accessible via the server's external IP address - which means that our in-development projects are accessible to the outside world.

How do we stop this happening?
We want it to still be accessible internally only.

Answer (score -1):

U just have to set up the apache virtualhost correctly, usually a vhost is set like:

< virtualhost *:80 >

u have to set it like

< virtualhost **192.168.1.0/24:80** >

This will affect all the apache folders, in alternative u can set the specific directory inside the virtual host like this example

< Directory "/Applications/MAMP/myproject/"> 
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride all
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     **Allow from 192.168.1.0/24**
< /Directory>